# How to decided which of multiple IP addresses (IPv4 or IPv6) assigned to my computer in PHP?

Tags: php

If I have multiple IP addresses (IPv4 or IPv6) assigned to my computer, how do I decide which IP address is used when making a file_get_contents() request to a HTTP URL (or using cURL)?

OS: Mac OS 10.8.5

Comment: It depends on the routing within your OS.

Comment: @mkaatman I changed the question to include the OS environment. It's MacOS 10.8.5

Comment: Create file that logs requester IP, use `file_get_contents()`, compare log IP with your IP addresses list.